# How to subset data.frame based on POSIXCt timestamp in R

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct

I want to subset the following data.frame based on the condition below.

```
> head(df1)
        timeStamp g_id p_k_id weekday
1 2015-01-05 15:00:00     848            266     Mon
2 2015-01-05 15:01:00     848            266     Mon
3 2015-01-05 15:02:00     848            266     Mon
4 2015-01-05 15:02:00     848            266     Mon
5 2015-01-05 15:02:00     848            266     Mon
6 2015-01-05 15:03:00     848            266     Mon

> str(df1)
'data.frame':   33150 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ timeStamp     : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:00" ...
 $ g_id       : Factor w/ 2 levels "","848": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ p_k_id     : Factor w/ 5 levels "","265","266",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ weekday    : Factor w/ 4 levels "Fri","Mon","Sat",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Condition:
rows where timestamp >= 2015-01-05 15:01:00 & <= 2015-01-05 15:02:00

Without using subset(), as I need to use it to create a function, not to use interactively.

I have tried:

```
df2 <- df1[df1$timestamp >= 2015-01-05 15:01:00 & <= 2015-01-05 15:02:00]
```

But this throws the error:

```
Error: unexpected '<=' in...
```

Thank you for pointers.

Comment: Probably something like `df1[with(df1, timeStamp >= "2015-01-05 15:01:00" & timeStamp <= "2015-01-05 15:02:00"), ]`

Comment: That's right, thanks @David Arenburg.